# Improving Mouse Wheel Algorithm Navigation for Slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, math, mousewheel

## Introduction

I have a page that has full screen `fixed` blocks and I would like to navigate these blocks using the javascript `wheel` event.

*If that doesn't make sense; to put it simply, I have a custom carousel that I would like to navigate using the mouse wheel one block at a time i.e one scroll roll/click moves to the previous/next item.*

My current solution works, but it needs a little tweaking to make it work better.

## The Issue

The problem I am having is that 1 roll/click on my mouse wheel sometimes scrolls one block, and sometimes scrolls 2 blocks.

The algorithim I am using is as follows:

- For every fired `wheel` event, increment/decrement the global variable `deltaY` value by 1 (my mouse wheel tends to fire around 35-40 events each time the wheel is scrolled when in click mode, not sure if this is standard)
- Whenever the `deltaY` value changes, determine which block (by index) should be `active`. I do this with the following; `Math.floor(deltaY / 35)` where `35` is the number of `wheel` events fired by 1 roll of my mouse wheel (very unsure about this as it may differ for other mice)
- Update the `active` index and update `deltaY` with an integer divisible by `35`

## The Code

I am using Vue.js but not to worry if you are not familiar with it, all I really need is the algorithm and I can implement it into my code.

### Vanilla JS

*I haven't tested this code, I simply mocked it up based on my Vue.js code for those of you that are not familiar with Vue.*

```
// Set the default values
let items  = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
let active = 0;
let deltaY = 0;

/**
 * Update the delta value and any other relevant
 * values.
 *
 * @param {event} event
 * @return void
 */
function updateDelta (value) {

    active = Math.floor(value / 35);
    deltaY = active * 35;

}

// Register the `wheel` event
window.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {

    // The navigation is only active when the page has not
    // been scrolled
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop === 0) {

        // If the last item is currently active then we do not need to
        // listen to `down` scrolls, or, if the first item is active, 
        // then we do not need to listen to `up` scrolls
        if (
            (event.deltaY > 0 && (active - 1) === items.length)
            || (event.deltaY < 0 && deltaY === 0)
        ) {
            return;
        }

        updateDelta(Math.sign(event.deltaY));

    }

}, { passive: true });
```

### My Code (Vue JS)

*I have added clear comments to illustrate what Vue is doing*

```
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            items: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
            active: 0, // Define the active index
            deltaY: 0 // This is used for the scroll wheel navigation
        }
    },

    created() {

        // Register the `wheel` event
        window.addEventListener('wheel', this._handleWheel, { passive: true });

    },

    destroyed() {

        // Remove the `wheel` event
        window.removeEventListener('wheel', this._handleWheel, { passive: true });

    },

    watch: {

        // I have added watchers to both `deltaY` and `active`, however,
        // this may not be necessary. These will not create an endless loop
        // because the watcher is only called when a value is changed

        active: function(index) {

            // Whenever the `active` index changes, update the `deltaY` value
            this.deltaY = index * 35;

        },

        deltaY: function(value) {

            // Whenever the `deltaY` value changes, update the `active` index
            this.active = Math.floor(value / 35);

        }

    },

    methods: {

        /**
         * Handle the window wheel event.
         *
         * @param {event} event
         * @return void
         */
        _handleWheel (event) {

            // The navigation is only active when the page has not
            // been scrolled
            if (document.documentElement.scrollTop === 0) {

                // If the last item is currently active then we do not need to
                // listen to `down` scrolls, or, if the first item is active, 
                // then we do not need to listen to `up` scrolls
                if (
                    (event.deltaY > 0 && (this.active - 1) === this.items.length)
                    || (event.deltaY < 0 && this.deltaY === 0)
                ) {
                    return;
                }

                this.deltaY += Math.sign(event.deltaY);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already pointed out yourself, the number of times a `wheel` event fires may vary from mice to mice and from time to time. Thus, relying on the number of events as a way to determine when to shift a block will always be unpredictable.

Instead, I suggest to try an alternative approach. For example, you could try to detect when the user stops scrolling, and just increment your index by 1. A quick Google search returned [this helper function](https://gomakethings.com/detecting-when-a-visitor-has-stopped-scrolling-with-vanilla-javascript/), which does just that.

Comment: I just tried listening to the wheel event, and found both the deltaY number and the number of events fired to be different everytime I scroll. I'm using a trackpad on a Macbook pro, and an Apple Magic Mouse. So there's no way your current approach will work for everyone.

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as a _single_ wheel roll for a trackpad.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that trackpads work differently. I wanted to get my mouse working properly before testing with my trackpad and my smooth scrolling on my mouse. I have managed to get it to work pretty well by just setting a high threshold, i.e. not estimating the number of events per 'scroll'